# Progress Dialog Not Dismissed

Tags: android, android-volley, progressdialog

I am working on catalog project which can do CRUD. On every CRUD process it show ProgressDialog.

The problem is the "Update data catalog" not dismissed and run forever until MJ forget how to rap. I don't understand why. Please help

**Code**

```
public void updateProduct(final String id, final String name, final String price, final String category, final String description, @Nullable String imageBase64) {
    Log.i("zihad", "updateProduct()");
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Update data catalog", "Please wait ...");
    StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.URL_SERVER+"/updateproduct.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String jsonResponse) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("zihad", "updateProduct().onResponse()");
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                        if (jObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Product has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            myDefaultErrorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> mapParam = new HashMap<>();
            mapParam.put("id", id);
            mapParam.put("name", name);
            mapParam.put("price", price);
            mapParam.put("category", category);
            mapParam.put("description", description);

            return mapParam;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(myStringRequest);

    if (imageBase64 != null) {uploadImageProduct(id, imageBase64);}
}

public void uploadImageProduct(final String id, final String imageBase64) {
    Log.i("zihad", "uploadImageProduct()");
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Upload image catalog", "Please wait ...");
    StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.URL_SERVER+"/uploadimage.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String jsonResponse) {
                    Log.i("zihad", "uploadImageProduct().onResponse()");
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            myDefaultErrorListener) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> mapParam = new HashMap<>();
            mapParam.put("id", id);
            mapParam.put("imageBase64", imageBase64);

            return mapParam;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(myStringRequest);
}
```

**Log Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: try using `progressDialog.cancel();` instead

Comment: You're using the same variable - `progressDialog` - for two different instances of `ProgressDialog`, and they're getting mixed up. Follow your log alongside the code. After `uploadImageProduct()` runs, `progressDialog` refers to the "Upload image catalog" instance.

Comment: @MikeM. the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your progress dialog to determinate. In your code after

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Update data catalog", "Please wait ...");
```

add this line :

```
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    dialog.show(); // show the dialog
    return dialog;
}
```

The callback method **onResponse** will not be call until their is an response from your server.

The show() method will create and **show** a Dialog for you, so if you call that method twice without dismissing the first one, the first one will not dismiss forever because the reference of that dialog will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final viewProgressDialogue viewProgressDialogue = new viewProgressDialogue(DebugActivity.this);
    viewProgressDialogue.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("response","im calling");
            viewProgressDialogue.dismiss();
        }
    }, 5000);
```